# What should .NET programmer learn in Java/Flex world (equivalents to ASP.MVC2, MEF, Prism, IoC and DI frameworks

Tags: java, .net, apache-flex, rich-internet-application

I'd like to play with Java/Flx and build RIA with Java as backend and Flex as frontend and if it would be necessary mayby some website (i don't know which framework right now, probably Spring + some Jquery)

But at the begining i'd like to know which technologies should i use. Now i'm ASP.NET (MVC2) + WPF and a bit Silverlight programmer and after about 3 months, while i's developing asp.mvc website, i've learnt many interesting things about building modular and extensible applications (MEF and Prism), about architecture (DI, IoC frameworks (ninject, Castle WIndsor, StructMap), EntityFramework as ORM, NHibernate)... I wish i'd know them all before i've started my adventure with .NET, now my website would be quite different :)

So here i'd like to ask You- advanced java/Flex programmers what should i know if i want to start develope really good, enterprise and flexible application...

Right now i've read some informations about Hibernate as ORM, Java Spring as web framework, BlazeDs to connect spring and Flex, and... I have no idea how good programmers cope with IoC Containers in Java/Flex world. Are there any frameworks? Something like mentioned above Ninject, Castle Windsor etc?

Where should i start if i'd like to build extensible applications. Divided on modules which can be developed by separated programmers' groups. Is there something like MEF or Prism for Java? Or mayby there are some other, better ways. I read something about OSGi (used in Eclipse) but i don't know is it a good way to create extensible application?

Thx in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if i have a direction to point you, but I'll throw out two clarifications.  JQuery is an AJAX framework and a front end technology.  It would be unusual to use that as part of a Flex application.  The second is that, if you already know .NET why not use .NET as the server side piece to your Flex app?  ( Not that I want to discourage you from learning new technologies, but from a business / time to market / maintenance standpoint it is often better to stick with what you know )

Comment: [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Yea i know what i Jquery :) i just said i'd like to write server which could be accessed thorugh ex. apps on mobile (in flex) and browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally speaking I would go with
I will answer your question short, with general issues, not drilling down too much.

I don't want to confuse you at this stage.

Flex

- MVC framework (RobotLegs, Cairngorm)
- Modularity (Potomac or custom)
- building application correctly

Java

- Hibernate
- remoting with flex (AMF and friends)

I think to get you started, this is great.

Also, just to agree with @flextras, I think if you already know .net, you should stick with it at first, learning flex is hard enough, learning flex and Java together is harder

When working with both, I would also

Comment: I don't want to stick to "one right" technology. I know that noone will know everything :) but right now i'm working in C# and .NET for about 1 year and i think it's good time to try something other. I like to learn :) Thx for informations. Besides i hope i'll learn more java, and flex will be additional. In future i hope i'll work with flex developers as java-backend programmer and now i want only know basics.